# How to remove scrollbar from each iframe element in HTML and adjust size of the iframe element to display all content without it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an index.html page containing a series of many iframe elements of varying heights/widths that embed other HTML documents. I want to display each iframe element on the page, but remove all of the scrollbars on each iframe element and have each element adjust its height and width automatically to fit all the content inside it.

I am keeping this index.html file in a repository which people can pull and locally open on their computer without needing to run a Node app or local server, making it as simple as possible and per design requirement.

This is what a few of my `iframe` elements look like:

```
<div>
  <iframe src="../repository/repo/build/auto/documents/layer1/generated_doc.html"></iframe>
  <iframe src="../repository/repo/build/auto/documents/layer1/generated_info.html"></iframe>
  <iframe src="../repository/repo/build/auto/documents/layer1/generated_log.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

I have tried to do a script as such, with no luck:

```
(function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", autoAdjustIframeHeight);
  function autoAdjustIframeHeight() {
    const iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    for (const iframe of iframes) {
      let contentWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
      let contentHeight = contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
      let contentWidth = contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
      iframe.style.height = contentHeight + 'px';
      iframe.style.width = contentWidth + 'px';
    }
  }
})();
```

as I get this error below, and the width/height of the elements stay default:

```
index.js:10 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

I would like to have a solution where I do not need to host a local server, and alter/display the iframe elements locally on my computer if possible.

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's so many articles on responsive iframes... And also about the specific issue (log error) you're facing.

Comment: User's filesystem files are all considered to be cross-origin from each other for security reasons.  This problem would disappear if your files were on a server.